# How to record the insertion time on table1 after inserting into table2?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
table1(id, data, insertion_time)
table2(id, data)
```

Need solution

1. when insert data in table1 then same data copy to table2
2. every row insertion time save in table1(insertion_time) column.

Need this solution for Oracle trigger

Comment: Are you asking for someone to post the code for a [AFTER INSERT trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php)?

Answer (score 2):

Use default value for `insertion_time` and a trigger for copying data.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table table1
  2  (id             number,
  3   data           varchar2(20),
  4   insertion_time date default sysdate
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create table table2
  2  (id             number,
  3   data           varchar2(20)
  4  );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_tab1
  2    after insert on table1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into table2 (id, data)
  6      values (:new.id, :new.data);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into table1 (id, data)
  2    select 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Foot'   from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from table1;

        ID DATA                 INSERTION_TIME
---------- -------------------- -------------------
         1 Little               24.09.2023 08:32:42
         2 Foot                 24.09.2023 08:32:42

SQL> select * from table2;

        ID DATA
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** based on your comment.

Well, as trigger fires as soon as you insert row into TABLE1, then `INSERTION_TIME` is just the same. There *might* be a difference of fractional seconds, but - is that relevant? If so, then remove default value and put it into the trigger (but this time change its type).

User `mike` will now contain `table2` which is accessed via database link:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table table2
  2  (id             number,
  3   data           varchar2(20)
  4  );

Table created.
```

Back to `scott`: create database link, `table1` and trigger:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_mike_t2
  2    connect to mike
  3    identified by lion
  4    using 'my_laptop:1521/xepdb1';

Database link created.

SQL> create table table1
  2  (id             number,
  3   data           varchar2(20),
  4   insertion_time date
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_tab1
  2    before insert on table1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.insertion_time := sysdate;
  6    insert into table2@dbl_mike_t2 (id, data)
  7      values (:new.id, :new.data);
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> insert into table1 (id, data)
  2    select 1, 'Little' from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> select * From table1;

        ID DATA                 INSERTION_TIME
---------- -------------------- -------------------
         1 Little               24.09.2023 08:55:02

SQL> select * from table2@dbl_mike_t2;

        ID DATA
---------- --------------------
         1 Little

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I mean Insertion_time mean table1 to table2 insertion_time. actually it need for 2 another table connect via db_link

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Wao.. Its working nice. Many many thanks bro.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil - Just note that using triggers to roll your own replication solution is rarely a good idea.  It is slow, it creates availability issues, and it is rare that you don't end up with bugs.  You'd almost certainly be better served creating a materialized view on the remote database that replicates data from the source and/or using GoldenGate.

Comment: JustinCave - Thanks for your suggestion.